# how to union 2 map into one with collection in value

Tags: java, list

how to union 2 maps into one with collection in value

```
HashMap<String, Collection<Integer>> map1 = new HashMap<String, Collection<Integer>>();
HashMap<String, Collection<Integer>> map2 = new HashMap<String, Collection<Integer>>();
map3 = new HashMap<>();

map3.putAll(map1);
map3.putAll(map2);
```

this way it will override the value

Comment: The real solution is to make an object/class that holds data for you, instead of multiple fields with nested generics

Comment: @Rogue completely not what i need

Comment: I mean if `HashMap<String,Collection<Integer>>map17` seems more readable than `SomeClass`, I'll eat my hat. But sometimes it helps to contain these operations instead of building your entire application out from a hierarchy of collections. Trying to find a name for the antipattern but it isn't coming to me. That said you already have a working solution, what exactly _do_ you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return Stream.concat(map1.entrySet().stream(), map2.entrySet().stream())
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(
               Map.Entry::getKey,
               Map.Entry::getValue,
               (ids1, ids2) -> {
                  final Set<Integer> merged = new HashSet<>(ids1);
                  merged.addAll(ids2);
                  return merged;
               }));

}
```

Comment: Note that this might lose any duplicates that are present in the original collections, i.e. merging lists `1,1,2,3` and `2,2,4` would result in `1,2,3,4` (or any other order) with the duplicate 1 and 2 in each source list gone.

Comment: @Thomas that's not a problem for me, this is why I'm using a set

Comment: If you wan't to have your code reviewed, post it one Code Review

Comment: Well, that's ok since you posted an answer to your own question and you know your requirements. They are, however, not stated in the question and your answer doesn't reflect that either so others who might look at this should at least be made aware.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `merge()` method like this.

```
Map<String, Collection<Integer>> map1 = Map.of(
    "a", List.of(0, 1),
    "b", List.of(10));
Map<String, Collection<Integer>> map2 = Map.of(
    "a", List.of(2, 3),
    "c", List.of(20));
Map<String, Collection<Integer>> map3 = new HashMap<>(map1);
for (Entry<String, Collection<Integer>> e : map2.entrySet())
    map3.merge(e.getKey(), e.getValue(), (v0, v1) -> {
        Collection<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(v0);
        list.addAll(v1);
        return list;
    });
System.out.println(map3);
```

output:

```
{a=[a0, a1, a2, a3], b=[b0], c=[c1]}
```

Comment: There's a slight problem with your code: it changes the original lists since `putAll()` won't put new copies.